# How to use appDataFolder & Google Picker without full drive scope permission?

Tags: google-drive-api, appdata, google-picker

**Problem I have encountered:**
 + Can not copy spreadsheet file, json file, .. to appDataFolder without full drive auth scope. 
 + Can not copy spreadhshet file to specific folder that was indentify by Google Picker.

**What I expected to happen:**

- Where can I find solution for these problem? I lost too much time to research about that but all information from community is too old.
- Can I copy file (spreadsheet, json, ...) from another drive to customer's drive (appDataFolder, specific folder) with use both technique: get drive.appdata scope and pick Google Picker dialog without full drive auth scope? If I can do it, please give me a guidance.
- If I can not copy file by just above technique, is it mean that I must have full drive auth scope in my addon to copy file & template?

**My situation:**

I created and published my first Google Sheet Addons but it was rejected by Google's Reviewer.

The main idea of this addon is use for a community on my website. They will use this addon to practice and learn about improving their skills. Our customers (with any gmail or GSuite mail) use our templates that was optimized for their life to think and follow many actions & data.

That is why we need more scopes of permission to help them process data through email, drive, spreadsheet and docs.

I need to control some data in Google Drive as metadata scope (to get/set comments and send it to our customers) or drive scope (to create/copy files from template library  by creating a folder by Google Picker). I also need to saved some hidden config spreadsheet in appDataFolder.

I tried to use drive.appdata and Google Picker to copy multi files (json file, Google Sheet file, ..) from our drive to customer’s drive appdata folder but It is not allow.

Please tell me how can I resolve it because the Google's reviewer not accept for full drive's scope in my addon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Picker uses the Drive API in the background, and to create or upload a file to a user's folder you **do need** the full Drive scope. If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#auth) you will see that:

> Some scopes are restricted and require a security assessment for your
>   app to use them. For more information, see the [authentication and
>   authorization page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing).

In this page there is a list of scopes and their meaning. In the case of `drive.file`:

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File
>   authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the
>   user deauthorizes the app.

This doesn't include writing on the user's Drive folder.